# Calendar to date timezone problem

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a date object which is parsed from a string using **SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").**

This date has the correct time, but not the correct day (It's in January 1970), so i create a calendar with that date. Than i create a calendar with the current date and set the hours and minutes to the hours and minutes from the previous calendar.

If i now use `newCal.getTime()` it gives me the correct dates for times between 12:00 and 23:59 but if i for example give 11:00 i get a date with 23:00h which i cannot explain.

Here the full code:

```
String dateString = "11:00";
//String dateString = "20:00";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

Date date = sdf.parse(dateString,new ParsePosition(0));

Calendar parsedCal = Calendar.getInstance();
parsedCal.setTime(date);

Calendar newCal = Calendar.getInstance();

newCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, parsedCal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
newCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, parsedCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

System.out.println(newCal.getTime());
```

For 20:00 i get the correct output for 11:00 i get 23:00 as mentioned.

Comment: have you checked if the date you created is the first on the DST? in that case you might lack of one hour depending on your zone.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Calendar.HOUR; you should be using [Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY)

Comment: +1, just please update your link to point to the java 1.6 docs

Comment: Sometimes i feel like hugging people :p Thank you! Can't believe i overlooked that..

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
    String dateString = "11:00";
    //String dateString = "20:00";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
    Calendar parsedCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    parsedCal.setTime(date);

    Calendar newCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    newCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, parsedCal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    newCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, parsedCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    newCal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, parsedCal.get(Calendar.AM_PM));

    System.out.println(newCal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at [Joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which has classes representing date, time and date-time. Your code snippet could be replaced by:

```
String dateString = "11:00";
LocalTime time = new LocalTime(dateString);

System.out.println(time.toDateTimeToday());
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of(
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ,  // Current date in a particular time zone.
    LocalTime.parse( "23:00" ) ,                        // Specify 11 PM.
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )                     // Specify a time zone as the context for this date and time. Adjustments made automatically if that date-time is not valid in that zone.
)
```

> 2018-01-23T23:00+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes instead of the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

### `java.time.LocalTime`

For a time-of-day only, without a date and without a time zone, use the `LocalTime` class.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "23:00" ) ;
```

To determine a specific point on the timeline with that time-of-day, apply a date (`LocalDate`) and a time zone (`ZoneId`) to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

### `ZoneId`

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" );
```

Use that zone to get the current date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Combine.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-01-23T23:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

Keep in mind that for that particular zone, your date and time-of-day may not be valid. The `ZonedDateTime` class adjusts automatically. Study the doc to be sure you understand and agree with its algorithm for that adjustment.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).